# how to priority dom execution in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i'm having a problem when i want to `document.getElementById();` in html tag.
example =

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="js"> //note this example is not found so browser is take time to execution
<script type="js"> //note this example is not found so browser is take time to execution
<script type="js"> //note this example is not found so browser is take time to execution
<script type="js"> //note this example is not found so browser is take time to execution
</head>
<body>
<div> ...
<div id="test">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my question is how to execution `document.getElementById("test");` without waiting load script is not found?that can make more time.how i can fix this.thanks for your answer.

note: solve not to remove or modify script to found directory.
just in case,if the script not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `defer="defer"` to those `<script />` tags for which you want to defer execution.

*NOTE: defer works on IE and newer versions of Firefox and Chrome*

Comment: any other suggestion because my browser also execution script not found. i just want to priority `document.getElementById("test");` is first execution.and i can get the innerHTML.

Comment: It's always better to load your JS files at the bottom of your page. See this why its better to load at the end : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page. Please mind, there's no `<srctype />`, it should be, `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/js/file"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [headJS](http://headjs.com/) which will load your scripts async and after `document.ready`.

What is another option, is to move the `srctype` to the bottom of the file so they are loaded last. But I don't think the `document.ready` will be executed untill the browser has loaded those files

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `<srctype>` is supposed to be `<script>`, and that what you're asking is what you can do about non-existent scripts being referenced from a page, the only possible answer is that you switch to a dynamic script loading approach like [LABjs](http://labjs.com) or something, or, of course, to stop including script tags that refer to non-existent scripts.

Browsers will always attempt to load and run `<script>` tags that aren't marked "async", and that of course is a fairly new attribute whose behavior is not quite uniform across even those browsers that support it.