# Swapping <p> with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, swap

I'm trying to swap two HTML paragraphs with a JavaScript button. The code seems to all check out, so I can't seem to figure out why it's not working!

HTML:

```
<p id="p1"> Donald Drumpf paced and loomed behind Hillary Clinton at times during Sunday night's second presidential debate -- a decision possibly driven by stress during the intensely bitter event, according to body language expert Janine Driver. </p>
<p id="p2"> "He's decreasing stress by doing all that movement," Driver said of Drumpf's behavior on CNN's "New Day" on Monday. </p>

<button onclick="swapT()"> Swap </button>
```

JS:

```
function swapT()
{
  var obj1 = document.getElementById('p1');
  var obj2 = document.getElementById('p2');

  var temp = obj1.innerHTML;
  obj1.innerHTML = obj2.innerHTML;
  obj2.innerHTML = temp;    
}
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: swapT is not defined

What's going wrong?

Comment: what is `innherHTML`?

Comment: Also `innterHTML`!

Comment: "Seems to check out" open the console, and you'll see that "seems" is not a good way to make sure your code is good.

Comment: @FastSnail Whoops, fixed that, still not getting them to swap though.

Comment: @showdev Uncaught ReferenceError: swapT is not defined

Comment: It is working: https://jsfiddle.net/matikucharski/wywujded/. You need to define function before you add it to html onclick

Comment: @MatiK Thanks! how do I define the function beforehand? (sorry I'm a newbie)

Comment: @DannyGarcia - include it in head - or somewhere in <script> before your html structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message you got, it seems that your `swapT()` function is bound to an inline handler before it's defined. If you're going to call the function from an inline handler, first define the function within the `<head>` of your document:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script>
    function swapT() {
      var obj1 = document.getElementById('p1');
      var obj2 = document.getElementById('p2');

      var temp = obj1.innerHTML;
      obj1.innerHTML = obj2.innerHTML;
      obj2.innerHTML = temp;

    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <p id="p1">Donald Drumpf paced and loomed behind Hillary Clinton at times during Sunday night's second presidential debate -- a decision possibly driven by stress during the intensely bitter event, according to body language expert Janine Driver.</p>
  <p id="p2">"He's decreasing stress by doing all that movement," Driver said of Drumpf's behavior on CNN's "New Day" on Monday.</p>

  <button onclick="swapT()">Swap</button>

</body>

</html>
```

My suggestion is to bind the listener when you define your function, instead:

```html
<html>

<body>

  <p id="p1">Donald Drumpf paced and loomed behind Hillary Clinton at times during Sunday night's second presidential debate -- a decision possibly driven by stress during the intensely bitter event, according to body language expert Janine Driver.</p>
  <p id="p2">"He's decreasing stress by doing all that movement," Driver said of Drumpf's behavior on CNN's "New Day" on Monday.</p>

  <button id="swap">Swap</button>

  <script>
    
    function swapT() {
      var obj1 = document.getElementById('p1');
      var obj2 = document.getElementById('p2');

      var temp = obj1.innerHTML;
      obj1.innerHTML = obj2.innerHTML;
      obj2.innerHTML = temp;
    }

    document.getElementById('swap').addEventListener('click', swapT);
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Here are some relevant links for further reference:

[Why put JavaScript in the footer of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391348/why-put-javascript-in-the-footer-of-a-page)
[Where to place Javascript in a HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file)
[Should I write script in the body or the head of the html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531314/should-i-write-script-in-the-body-or-the-head-of-the-html)
[Does javascript have to be in the head tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213281/does-javascript-have-to-be-in-the-head-tags)

Comment: This makes so much more sense. Thanks a ton!