# How to remove a class from a link... on only one page?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a 404.php page and would like to remove the "current state" class from a link, only on that page.

As of right now this is what I've got...

```
jQuery( function() {

    if ( TEMPLATE_URI + '/404.php'.hasClass( '.current_page_parent' ) ) {

            jQuery( '.menu' ).removeClass( '.current_page_parent' );
    }

});
```

which does not seem to be working.

I am a beginner in the subject of jQuery so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work :

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('404.php') != -1){
     jQuery('.current_page_parent').removeClass('current_page_parent')
}
```

Also, when using removeClass, you don't need to put the dot.

Comment: It is a wild guess since in his question, he is (i think) searching for a string '404.php'

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress automatically uses the file 404.php to show 404 error pages.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) So you don't have to check for 404.php in your code.

Just put this Javascript code in the file 404.php, [preferrably at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.menu').removeClass('current_page_parent');
});
</script>
```

Otherwise, you can use the function `is_404()` in any template (PHP) file to see if the current page is a 404 error page. Something like this:

```
<?php if (is_404()): ?>
jQuery('.menu').removeClass('current_page_parent');
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is still failing to work! the script does nothing and the php prints on the screen.

Here's a link to show you what I've got goin' on... [link](http://wordpress-dev.designer17.com/portfoloi/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help @Christian Daven and @Karl-Andre Gagnon! Basically what I did was combine bits of both answers and got this (which I have placed in my 404 Template page)...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        jQuery( '.current_page_parent' ).removeClass( 'current_page_parent' );

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Saying that you could play in the 404 template would have been a good add-on to your question ^^, Add every usefull information in your next question!