# Revealing module pattern and document onready

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, document-ready, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to implement a Canvas game using the revealing module pattern. As such, I have to get the Canvas DOM element and its context. This means that the function should not be executed until the DOM is fully loaded. Since I'm using jQuery, I was just going to throw everything in a document.ready(), but that messes with the scopes. As you can see by this example:

```
var game = function ()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var init = function ()
    {
    }

    return 
    {
        init: init
    }
}();
```

The function has to be self-executing in order for the return to work correctly. Since it references the canvas, however, I don't want it to load immediately. Putting the self-executing function in document.ready() prevents me from doing

```
game.init();
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insure that a DOM element is loaded before a particular piece of javascript runs, simply put the javascript after that  particular DOM element on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            game.init();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        var game = function () {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var init = function () {
                alert(canvas.id);
            };
            return {
                init: init
            }
        }();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is parsed from top to bottom, so that canvas element will be loaded into the DOM before the javascript code executes.

An additional benefit of putting your javascript at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag is that this can improved the perceived load time of your page.  If you have complicated javascript in the head section of your page, for example, this javascript will have to be loaded and parsed before any of the HTML elements in the body section can be rendered, since the page executes from the top down.  If the javascript is complicated, the page can appear to load slowly.  By putting it on the bottom, your HTML is rendered and then your javascript is loaded and parsed, which can make the visual parts of your page appear more quickly.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page) for more information.