# Load HTML into a DIV using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a index.html, there is a DIV where I want the rest of HTML files to be loaded by clicking on the buttoms, here I have an example:
[image]

I have tried lots of examples that I've found on google but none of them is working. Here I have the last code I've use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>  

<script src="jquery/reflection.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">  </script>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/css.css" media="all" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(page) {
        $("#content").load(page);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>  

<div id="cabecera">
    <a href="javascript:change('contacto.html');"><button style="float:right; margin-right:49px;" type="button" name="btn_der" value="" class="menu_principal" id="btn_der">CONTACT</button></a>
    <button style="float:right;" type="button" name="" value="" class="menu_principal">PRODUCTS</button>
    <button style="float:right;" type="button" name="" value="" class="menu_principal" id="btn_izq">HOME</button>
</div>

<div id="cuerpo">
    <div id="content"></div> <!--This is the one where rest of html file should be loaded -->

<div id="tablet" class="reflect">
    <img src="imagenes/tablet.png" class="reflect">
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

By other hand, is it possible that when I first load index.html HOME buttom appears on active state??
I would appreciate any help. Thanxs a lot.

Comment: This looks like pretty basic stuff. Did you look it up in any resource?

Comment: And what happens when you click the button? Does the browser catch on fire? You have no click events on the buttons so how are they supposed to load the page. Reason you are reinventing iframes?

Comment: You didn't find anything? You clearly didn't look hard enough. Maybe use jQuery .hide() and .show() for each button, that could be a simple start?

Comment: You can check it in here: www.globalapplicationsusa.com

Comment: Does that come with any javascript code or do you think $("#content").load(page) works like magic ? @epascarello : lol ^_^

Comment: Firebug tells me `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. This makes me think that jQuery is not loading correctly. Plus you did not close your `<link...` tag for the CSS. Check out these things and let us know what you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the show hide jq are what you need to use here.
Here is a link that I put together.

```
$("#homeButton").click(function () {
    $("#cuerpo").show() ;
    $("#tablet").hide() ;

});

$("#procuctsButton").click(function () {
    $("#tablet").show() ;
    $("#cuerpo").hide() ;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jebr224/GEZth/

You could also try using iframe, you could make the buttons change the src of the frame.

Comment: Shouldn't buttoms stay at active state when you click on them?

Comment: The code does not put them into an active state.If you want that to be done, then just write it into the .click(function). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Why does it not work?

View your console.

```
GET http://www.globalapplicationsusa.com/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js 404 (Not Found) 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Your link to the jQuery file is broken so the code is not even running.

Comment: You were right but I did have it on localhost (were I was trying) but not on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script tag to the bottom of the page, or atleast behind the content div. 
Not 100% sure so don't shoot me if I'm wrong, but I think javascript will execute and the #content div is not yet loaded into the DOM. 
So the javascript cant find the element.

[JavaScript at bottom/top of web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page)

Comment: But why do buttoms don't stay actived??

Comment: Actually there's something strange... This is not working on localhost but it's working on the server