# Max-Height Firefox/Opera/IE

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a max-height to an image. It works well in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox/Opera/IE. Now I read that html and body heights should be put at 100%, and it did work when I used jsfiddle. However, it doesn't work in my page (memo-designs.com/portfolio.php).

The following is the source of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>memodesigns</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style/stylesheet.css'>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            function displayImage(image, link) {
                document.getElementById('img').src = image;
                document.getElementById('mylink').href = link;
            }

            function displayNextImage() {
                if (x < images.length-1){
                    x++;
                } else {
                    x = 0;
                }
                displayImage(images[x], links[x]);           
            }

            function displayPreviousImage() {
                if (x > 0){
                    x--;
                } else {
                    x = images.length-1;
                }
                displayImage(images[x]);           
            }

            function startTimer() {
                setInterval(displayNextImage, -1);
            }

          var images = [], links = [], x = 0;images[0] = "http://memo-designs.com/items/doublek-01.png"
links[0] = "http://memo-designs.com/items/doublek-01.png"
images[1] = "http://memo-designs.com/items/memodesigns.png"
links[1] = "http://memo-designs.com/items/memodesigns.png"

      </script>
    </head>

    <body style = 'background-color: #000000'><div id = 'menucontainer'>
            <div id = 'menu'>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = '/'>HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'about.php'>ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'portfolio.php'>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'rates.php'>RATES</a></li>
                        <li><a class = 'menu' href = 'contact.php'>CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div id = 'contentcontainer' style = 'padding-top: 0%; max-height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #000000'>
                <p>
                    <img id= 'img' src = 'http://memo-designs.com/items/doublek-01.png' style = 'max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
                    <img class = 'arrow' onclick = 'displayPreviousImage()' id= 'img' src = 'style/graphics/larrow.png' style = 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 40%;'>
                    <img class = 'arrow' onclick = 'displayNextImage()' id= 'img' src = 'style/graphics/rarrow.png' style = 'position: absolute; right: 0; top: 40%;'>          </p>
            </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

And the css stylesheet (only part of it is shown here):

```
*{
    margin:  0;
    padding:  0;
}

html{
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f3f4f4;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Would appreciate any help as to what I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: Try changing things like `<div id = 'menu'>` to `<div id="menu">` and see if that helps.

Comment: Message: Unable to set property 'href' of undefined or null reference
Line: 9

Comment: Removed that line, problem persists :/

Comment: writing on an answer atm. be patient :)

Comment: Ok, answer posted. Another resource that might be useful for you: http://perishablepress.com/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend you to start using a [CSS-Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) like [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) . It makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards.

Your HTML notation might also cause inconsistency across browsers. Turn things like `<div id = 'menu'>` into `<div id="menu">`. This makes it also more readable IMHO.

Inline style attributes make maintaining the pages a pain and may override things you didn't intent to. They also need to be applied to every single element thus also increasing download time. Using classes / id's is the way to go. Also pseudo-elements can't be used with inline styles. I advice to only use them for quick changes during development. I use the element inspector from Chrome / Firefox to change things quickly and instantly see how the changes look, copy/pasting the edits afterwards.

So, make sure to put all css into your stylesheet. It's also considered as a best practice for [maintainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162805/writing-maintainable-code) and better download speed ([minify](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) the files for production) of your pages.

You surely have heard about jQuery before. Try using it. jQuery makes developing things like image sliders a breeze (once you understand the syntax, but it's a low learning curve). Furthermore, there are LOTS of [ready-to-use plugins for jQuery](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20image%20slider).

Another "good practice" is to put your javascripts at the very end of your document just before the `</body>` tag. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1638670/2493918) and [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/).

**Ok, enough tips. Let's get the hands dirty:**

*The HTML Part:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>memodesigns</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="menuContainer">
        <div id="menu">
            <p>
                <ul>
                    <!-- Instead of writing in CAPITALS use the text-transform:uppercase; css property -->
                    <li><a class="menu" href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="rates.php">Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contentContainer">
        <p>
            <!-- NOTE: Use IDs only once, else use classes to share css styles -->
            <img id="img" src="http://memo-designs.com/items/doublek-01.png">
            <img class="arrow left" src="style/graphics/larrow.png" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">
            <img class="arrow right" src="style/graphics/rarrow.png" onclick="displayNextImage()">
        </p>
    </div>


    <!-- Put the JavaScript at the end of the document just before the closing body tag -->
    <script>
        var images = [], links = [], x = 0,
            baseUrl   = "http://memo-designs.com/items/";
            images[0] = baseUrl + "doublek-01.png";
            links[0]  = baseUrl + "doublek-01.png";
            images[1] = baseUrl + "memodesigns.png";
            links[1]  = baseUrl + "memodesigns.png";

        function displayImage(img, link)
        {
            document.getElementById('img').src = img;
            document.getElementById('mylink').href = link;
        }

        function displayNextImage()
        {
            if (x < images.length-1) x++; 
                else x = 0;

            displayImage(images[x], links[x]);           
        }

        function displayPreviousImage()
        {
            if (x > 0) x--; 
                else x = images.length-1;

            displayImage(images[x]);           
        }

        function startTimer()
        {
            setInterval(displayNextImage, -1);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

*...and the CSS:*

```
/* Assuming you'll use a CSS-Reset */
body {
    background-color: #f3f4f4;
    font:
    ...

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menuContainer { ... }
#menu { ... }
#menu ul { ... }

/* Making the menu labels all UPPERCASE */
#menu ul > li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#contentContainer {
    background-color: #000;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* IMPORTANT: Set a fixed pixel height here to make the images use up the given space */
    height: 200px; /* change 200 to your needs */
}
#img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#contentContainer .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
}
#contentContainer .arrow.left {
    left: 0;
}
#contentContainer .arrow.right {
    right: 0;
}
```

Ok, try out the suggestions and the code example. Tell us if and what helped.

**Good luck and happy coding!**

Comment: hmm I'll try it out later on tonight. This website is kinda urgent. I restarted from scratch the portfolio, and got it working across all browsers. What I did is use a new css stylesheet just for this page. I know it's not optimal, but as I said I am in a hurry. Thanks a lot, I'll try it out!