# How to make top bar go transparent when scrolling down?

Tags: css

Right now i have one bar located on top and here is the `CSS` for it:

```
#header_bar { 
  background: #000000;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10020;
}
```

My question is, how i can make this bar go transparent when the page is scrolled?

Should i use opacity option somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to make your nav bar transparent, yes, you want `opacity`.  To cause that to happen when you scroll...I don't think you can do that with just `CSS`.  You will likely need JavaScript/JQuery.

Comment: How i can make it with Javascript?

Comment: @TonnyStruck if Josh's answer solved your issue you should mark it as accepted so the community knows the problem is solved and so he gets credit :)

Answer (score 5):

I like the JQuery solutions here, but for completeness wanted to include a JavaScript solution in case anyone was looking for that.

The following will fade the navigation bar when it is not at the top, and return it to a solid color when it is.

```
function fadeNav(){  
  var offset = getScrollXY();
  //if y offset is greater than 0, set opacity to desired value, otherwise set to 1
  offset[1] > 0 ? setNavOpacity(0.5) : setNavOpacity(1.0); 
}

function setNavOpacity(newOpacity){
  var navBar = document.getElementById("header_bar");
  navBar.style.opacity = newOpacity;
}

function getScrollXY() {
  var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;
if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
  //Netscape compliant
  scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
  scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
  //DOM compliant
  scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
  scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft ||     
  document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
  //IE6 standards compliant mode
  scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
}

  return [ scrOfX, scrOfY ];
}
```

And of you would call it by adding this in script blocks on your page ([at the bottom is best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onscroll = fadeNav;
</script>
```

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/29bNn/1/)

Credit for the `getScrollXY()` function goes to: [this site - function is at the bottom](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)

Answer (score 3):

With pure css you will not be able to achieve this effect but by using jQuery to manipulate the css then you can.

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $('#header_bar').css({opacity: 0});
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/4RETE/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $('#header_bar').animate({opacity: 0});
});
```

[JSFIDDLE Fading out .animate](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/4RETE/1/)

If you want it to come back once you reach the top again then let me know!

**Fade back in at top** (Seems to fade in very slow)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $('#header_bar').animate({opacity: 0});

   if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
      $('#header_bar').animate({opacity: 1}); 
   }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE fade in/out](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/4RETE/12/)

**Hide and show**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $('#header_bar').hide(500);

   if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
      $('#header_bar').show(500); 
   }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE show/hide](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/4RETE/13/)

Comment: Thank you so much, but when it comes back to top it not appears again. How i can fix that?

Comment: Give me one second and I'll have it up and running for you. :p

Comment: Nice mate, can't wait to see it!

Comment: Alright I add two options, The first one I will have to figure out why it is fading back in so slow and the second one, hides/shows the div.

Comment: its because every time you scroll you apply opacity, so it gets applied multiple times, each mouse scroll, at the top you only undo 1, hence the problem, it should only be set once. I'll post solution in a sec.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with just CSS, you'll need JavaScript/jQuery. Here's a little jQuery code snippet that will fade it in and out:

```
var opacity = 1;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st == 0)
        $('#header_bar').css('opacity','1');

    if (opacity > 0.5 && (st > lastScrollTop)){
       $('#header_bar').css('opacity','-=0.01');
       opacity -= 0.01;
    }
    else if(opacity < 1)
    {
       $('#header_bar').css('opacity','+=0.01');
        opacity += 0.01;
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LBHvD/

Comment: Very interesting answer man! I'm not sure if it pertains to his question but +1 for awesomeness.

Answer (score 1):

This works great for me, and you can change the fadeTo to animation and works just as great.

> ```
>  var scroll_transparency = false;
>
>  $(window).scroll(function() {
>
>     // $('div.navbar-main-top').hide(500);
>
>     if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
>         scroll_transparency = false;
>         $('div.navbar-main-top').fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
>
>     } else {
>         if (scroll_transparency == false) {
>             $('div.navbar-main-top').fadeTo( "fast", .9 );
>             scroll_transparency = true;
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: change the 2nd if to this to cope with the bouncy scroll on the mac: if (scroll_transparency == false && $(window).scrollTop() > 0)