# Insert javascript into html

Tags: javascript

How do i insert this code into a html from a external .js file?

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout("time_date(), 1000");
}

function time_date() {
    ourDate = new Date();
    document.getElementById("cap1").innerHTML = "La fecha y la hora en la ubicación de su equipo es: " + ourDate.toLocaleString();

    document.getElementById("cap2").innerHTML = "El desfase entre la hora local y la zona horaria es GMT " + ourDate.getTimezoneOffset() + " minutes ";

    document.getElementById("cap3").innerHTML = "La hora y la fecha (GMT) son: " + ourDate.toGMTString() + ".<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code between `<HEAD>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="timedate.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already have that,but i want to insert that code into a <div> lets say.i want to control where the time will show.

Comment: Javascript code should not be inserted into a div. Let it in a Javascript file, and make the code write where it should. For example, your code actually write into `#cap1`, `#cap2` and `#cap3` divs.

Comment: It should work like that.It has to write into the cap1,2,3 but it doesn't.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the use of  `setTimeout`.

Comment: Try this : `setTimeout("time_date()", 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Insert a script tag just before the closing `</body>` if you don't need your javascript to run before the page is loaded. The page will be loaded before the JavaScript and displayed faster than if you included the script in the `head`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_script.js"></script>
</body>
```

More information on where to put js files can be found there :
[JavaScript at bottom/top of web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page)

And I think you have a problem without your timeout, it should read :

```
setTimeout(time_date, 1000);
```

And a typo : there is an unexpected `)` in your last line.