# Jquery $ Not defined, but it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, include

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
function updateData(){
  $('#ajax').load('./alerts.php', function(){
    setTimeout(updateImage, 2000);
  });
};

updateData();
});
</script>
```

That above $ is where devtools js console see's the error. on the $(document)

But I am CDN'ing jQuery at the bottom of this page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I keep reading the following,

That error can only be caused by one of three things:

1. Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
2. You have a botched version of jQuery. This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.
3. You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

a. Why wouldn't it be?

b. Its from jQuery's page for CDN

c. No its at the bottom...

Comment: Your script should be after the jquery script

Comment: the `<script>` loading library should be added first, it does not involve any DOM so it should be loaded first.

Comment: a - it can be latency big enough so your $(...) executed before jquery loaded.

Comment: @logo: have you hosted the app somewhere.

Comment: Move your script to after the CDN'ing

Comment: Your script is at the top of the page and you're loading jQuery at the bottom of the page. Your script must come after the jQuery load.

Comment: App is hosted at Digital Ocean. Auth is required tho.

Comment: Why do a lot of people say include JS at the BOTTOM. And then in this case I should load it at the top?

Comment: well, you should then include all the js at the bottom, including your script, which should come AFTER the CDN'ing

Comment: Moving it to the top... testing, well that fixed it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page

Comment: Okay what about in the same document <script> tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer both your main question and the question in the comments:

1) You must include/load your jQuery script **after** you called/loaded jQuery libraries.

2) If you want js to be at the bottom of the page, you can move everything js to the bottom, but make sure you call/load jQuery libs first, before you load your script.

Comment: Thank you, this makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the resources are loaded.
What is your protocol to access your html files ?
If you are using file://, the browser can't get the CDN resources.

Comment: No its hosted. I had to load the JS at the top. But in other stack answers people say load it at the bottom... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script tag with the code is before the jQuery imports.

Comment: of course! js is supposed to be loaded at the bottom, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page

Comment: So is your script tag under your jquery import "at the bottom"?