# JavaScript top or bottom - location sensitive?

Tags: javascript

Why does a linked JavaScript file sometimes not work when it is included at the top of the page and not at the bottom?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"..."></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript at bottom/top of web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page)

Comment: @codejak - This isn't a duplicate of the question you linked to, because this is specifically about why a file may not work if included at the top and that other question doesn't really cover that. (I'll be surprised if it isn't a duplicate of some other question though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if you want to manipulate DOM items, and those are not yet existing, it won't work. If the JavaScript file is included in the head, the body is not existing yet, but if you include it at the end of the body, those items are valid.

If you don't want to rely on this behaviour, you may define a callback, which is run, when the document is ready, i.e. when the whole of the DOM is loaded already.

This is what e.g. jQuery achieves with `$(document).ready(function() {})`, or more shortly `$(function () {});`. In vanilla JavaScript (using modern browsers, so IE9+) this can be achieved using

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // code...
});
```

Comment: It really depends on when do you choose to manipulate, or attach event handlers to DOM elements. If they are wrapped in a DOM ready function or a window onload function, then the script can exist virtually anywhere on the page ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know why is it not working is by checking for JS error. Try to find out what errors you are getting when the script has been included at the top. As mentioned in the other response it can be because of DOM items. You can circumvent this issue by adding a "defer" tag to the script.

It can also be because of some JS object you are expecting to be present when this script runs. For example if your script tag is serving a JSONP request then you must have the function that processes the data. Otherwise you will get a "undefined function" error when the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

JS code is executed instruction by instruction from top to bottom.

The code that calls a function needs to be **under** that functions definition.

This code works:

```
  var func = function()
  {
    alert('it works');
  };

  func();
```

While this doesn't:

```
  func();

  var func = function()
  {
    alert('it works');
  };
```

It throws an undefined error. The reason for this is that JS compiler is not aware of the func definition at the time it tries to call it.

Same goes for the JS files included in your HTML page. You can include them at the bottom as long as there are not dependencies in above sections, or, if they do not try to manipulate HTML code before page load.

Comment: But the OP asked about including the whole script at either the top or bottom of the html page - your second example wouldn't work either way.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, my last update addresses this issue as well.