# JavaScript on top or bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, If I place my JS on top, my form won't be able to submit. But if I place my JS on the bottom, my file list won't be able to get remove selectively.

What should I do?

Should I edit my JS? Or is there any other better way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript at bottom/top of web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use all js code after your document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
});
```

Wrap all js code inside this scope so that everything works after the initial DOM is populated. Otherwise DOM related problems occur.

Comment: Thanks! But I've already found a cleaver way and it work! I simply create a dummy hidden form on top, and the rest of the top is now able to submit successfully.

Comment: But don't worry, your answer I still accept it! But only in about 2 minutes time.

Comment: Thats great if you found alternate way, but the general rule is loading js code after initial DOM load completed, this will help you in future coding.

Comment: Yes, it would! Thanks again for the help